# session undefined in nodejs with express and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, session, express

I am using express, node.js and mysql here is my code

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); 
var urlEncodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}); 
var session = require('client-sessions'); 
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();

//mysql

var mysql = require("mysql");


app.post('/login', function(request, response){
    var body = request.body;        
    connection.query("select * from registeration where username='"+body.username+"' and password='"+body.pwd+"'",function(err, rows){
        if(err) { 
            console.log("username and password are not matched.");      
            response.end();
        } else {
            console.log("done");
            response.send(rows);
            request.usersession.user = user;        
            response.redirect(301, '/account');
        }   
    });

});

app.get('/account', function (request, response){       
    if(request.usersession && request.usersession.user) {          
        response.Send({requ: request.usersession.user});

        response.write('user detail ' + request.usersession.user[0]['username']);
        console.log('account in');
    }else{
        console.log('session error');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post more of your code, i'm missing some variable declarations. For example the user and the session variable.

Comment: app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'usersession',
  secret: '0GB2ZbiKBtz2flRPvlJZ9EtczCewBxXK',
 duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5
}));

Comment: app.post('/login', function(request, response){

 var body = request.body;
 
 connection.query("select * from registeration where username='"+body.username+"' and password='"+body.pwd+"'",function(err, user){
    if(err) { 
    console.log("username and password are not matched.");
  response.end();
    } else {
    console.log("done");
  request.usersession.user = user;
  
  response.redirect(301, '/account');
    }
 });

});

Comment: Please add it in the question by editing.

Comment: its not allow me to add code

Answer (score 0):

Add redirect to /login when not authenticated yet:

```
app.get('/account', function (request, response){       
    if(request.usersession && request.usersession.user) {          
        response.Send({requ: request.usersession.user});

        response.write('user detail ' + request.usersession.user[0]['username']);
        console.log('account in');
    }else{
        console.log('session error');

        // here you should redirect to login:
        response.redirect('/login');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can delete that line

Comment: which line please explain i am new to node.js

Comment: The line that has the "non-mysql" error you saw, but haven't shaw us. If I'm guessing it correctly, it's the 1st line after the "else"

Comment: thar is nothing its just a console.log message

Comment: Oh yes? So maybe answer @GiveMeAllYourCat's questions? You're using connection without having it assigned anywhere. Ah and the "non-mysql" errors ;) ... Deleting the console log will remove one "non-mysql" error. If you mean something else, the be so kind and TELL US WHAT ERROR!

Comment: is there any way to send my file so that you can check

Comment: Edit the question and include all important detail

Comment: what is the main reason why session value is not set ? Is that mysql query don't fetch data?

Comment: If the above is the whole code you try, then the reason is that you copy&pasted different parts of the code from different places but forgot to do the changes to match them. For example as I already mentioned you use "connection" but you don't assign to it any value previously. Probably you miss some code like connection=mysql.connect(...)

Comment: var mysql = require("mysql");


//connection strings for mysql

var connection = mysql.createConnection({

 host: "localhost",
 
 user: "root",
 
 password: "",
 
 database: "nodetest"

});

connection.connect();

Comment: there is no mistake in connection because my data is inserting into table